# ¿Porque no se muestran los elementos de menú de Angular material?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Tengo este problema, y el caso es que se supone que todo está hecho de forma correcta. Cuando intento que se vea un menu, tal y como especifican en la documentación de componentes de Angular material no se ven. Adjunto mi código para que os hagáis una idea:

```
<header id="mainHeader">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>
  </mat-toolbar>
</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer>
  <mat-toolbar color="accent">
    <small></small>
  </mat-toolbar>
</footer>
```

Este que veis es mi `app.component.html`.
Ahora adjunto el código del app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TITULO';
}
```

El caso es que no he tocado nada, lo he hecho directamente en un proyecto desde cero para ver podía encontrar el porqué, pero nada...

Adjunto el código de `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
```

¿Alguien ve si me falta algo o lo estoy haciendo de forma incorrecta? Nunca se me había planteado este problema, pero llevo un rato haciendo pruebas, y no lo llego a entender. Gracias de antemano por la atención prestada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falto agregar el

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
```

a tu codigo

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
```

para que te salga el menu quedaria asi

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button> 
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
            <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
        </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
```

[Ejemplo de Angular Material](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nvvbnlojjrgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar-overview-example.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias, Andrés Abadía. Estás en lo cierto. Pero al final lo que pretendía era tener los enlaces sin estar encerrados en el menú. Con lo cual el mat-menu, no sería necesario. Había confundido conceptos y la forma de usar el "mat-menu". No obstante, te agradezco mucho que me hayas sacado de la duda. Gracias.